# How to get IDE support for Aspect J Working in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, aspectj, ajdt

I am working on a Spring Roo/ApsectJ project at the moment. I am able to build a project and run it without any issues, implying AspectJ is doing correct weaving at compile time, however in Eclipses I seem to have no IDE support.  Any methods I am calling within the .aj files are being flagged as invalid (as they cant be linked to the class through AspectJ), and my Cross References view is not working.

Could someone point me in the right direction as to what area of configuration I need to explore to get the IDE "run time" support of AspectJ working in Eclipse...as the compile time support is working fine.

Any ideas appreciated.

i

Answer (score 1):

You have to install the AspectJ Development Tools in Eclipse: `Help` -> `Eclipse Marketplace...` -> Search for `ajdt`.

Comment: Hi,Thats the problem, I do have Version: 2.2.2.e42x-RELEASE-20130220-1400 installed - I am using Spring STS Eclipse Release.

Comment: @user1754307: right click your project and select `Configure` -> `Convert to AspectJ Project`. If that option isn't available, check the project properties if the AspectJ Builder is already added.

Comment: Hi,  this is already converted to an AspectJ Project.  I have tried remove the AspectJ project facet and re-adding it but it still doesn't give IDE support - but manages to compile.  To be honest I am a java developer of 6 weeks, and am not sure where else to look in terms of project preferences.